# Вывод в файл и чтение из текстового файла

Tags: java, io

Что нужно записать в строку `writer.write();`, для вывода всей информации которая была введена пользователем и отображена через `NewAircraf.ShowInfo()`.

```
 if (str.equals("y"))
     {
        System.out.println("Тип самолета :");
        typeAir = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Номер борта(6 цифр) :");
        bortAir = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Количество рейсов :");
        numberAir = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Налет в часах :");
        hoursAir = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Налет в тыс.км. :");
        kmAir = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());

       Transportation NewAircraft = new Transportation(typeAir,bortAir,numberAir,hoursAir,kmAir);
        NewAircraft.ShowInfo();

        try{
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile,true));
            writer.write( ); //вывести информацию которую заполнил пользователь
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Можно воспользоваться методом `Files.write()`, что проще, чем работа через `Writer`-классы. Например, так: `Files.write(Paths.get("/path/to/file"), newAircraft.toString().getBytes());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `Writer`, от которого наследуется класс `BufferedWriter`, есть [метод](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String)), который помещает переданную строку в буфер:

```
public void write(String str) throws IOException
```

Осуществить запись можно с помощью него, или с помощью [других методов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write-int-).

> Что нужно записать в строку `writer.write();`, для вывода всей информации которая была введена пользователем и отображена через `NewAircraf.ShowInfo()`.

Это зависит от того, как реализован метод `ShowInfo()`.

---

Если в классе `Transportation` переопределен метод `toString()`, то достаточно будет:

```
writer.write(NewAircraft.toString());
```

Если же этот метод не переопределен, но есть геттеры полей, то:

```
writer.write("TypeAir: " + NewAircraft.getTypeAir() + ...);
```

, где `...` -- вызов геттеров для остальных полей.

Первый вариант лучше, к тому же IDE может сама сгенерировать метод `toString()` (например, в Intellij IDEA: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> - `toString()`).

**PS. В Java принято именовать названия переменных и методов в `lowerCamelCase`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.write(NewAircraf.toString(),
     0,
     NewAircraft.toString().length());
```